# protobufjs : encoding/decoding a message that has an Any component

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, protobufjs

I am using protobufjs 6.6.3 (running on nodejs 6.9.1)
On short, I am trying to encode/decode a message that has a component of type Any and I am wondering if I am doing it right...

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

package myTest;

message TestMessage {
  string message = 1;
  google.protobuf.Any details = 2;
}
```

My initial question was : what is happening when I am decoding a message of type TestMessage : does it automatically decodes the Any part as well, or I need to do it 'manually'?

Briefly, this is what I did:

- created a new Any message
- attach it to a TestMessage message
- encode/decode TestMessage message; then,decode the Any part of the TestMessage

Code:

```
const protobuf = require('protobufjs');
const protoFile = __dirname + '/testAnyProto.proto';

function AnyMessageType(properties) {
    protobuf.Message.call(this, properties); // call the super constructor
}

var root = protobuf.loadSync(protoFile);
protobuf.Class.create(root.lookup('google.protobuf.Any'), AnyMessageType);

var sampleBuffer = new Buffer('ABCDEF', 'utf8');
var sampleAny = new AnyMessageType({
    type_url: "some.type",
    value: sampleBuffer
});

var sampleAnyEncodedBuffer = AnyMessageType.encode(sampleAny).finish();
var sampleAnyEncodedDecoded = AnyMessageType.decode(sampleAnyEncodedBuffer);
//just checking if I am getting back 'ABCDEF' and... I am
console.log(sampleAnyEncodedDecoded.value.toString('utf8'));

var TestMessageType = root.lookup('myTest.TestMessage');
// Create a new message
var testMessage = TestMessageType.create({
    message: 'Some message',
    details: sampleAny //??? when I decode a testMessage, it creates an AnyMessageType, so I assume I am right
});

var encodedTestMessage = TestMessageType.encode(testMessage).finish();
var decodedEncodedTestMessage = TestMessageType.decode(encodedTestMessage);
console.log(decodedEncodedTestMessage.details.value.toString('utf8'));
```

OK... so, the questions:

1. When I am building a TestMessage, *details* is expected (as per proto) to be filled with an AnyMessage message, not with an encoded AnyMessage message, correct?
2. The decoding of an encoded TestMessage message, does not automatically decode the AnyMessage component (*details*), correct? At least, this is how it looks to me...
3. What puzzles me the most, and therefore I need the above confirmations ... where am I supposed to use the AnyMessage encoding/decoding (I mean *sampleAnyEncodedBuffer = AnyMessageType.encode(sampleAny).finish()* call and the *decode* one)? Just for encoding/decoding simple AnyMessage (by simple I mean not part of a 'parent' message)?

    Let me put it like this : **I am trying to match the existing Java pack/unpack functions**.In my example, I am now 'associating' these with the buffer<->string conversion (see my last console.log line) and I don't see the need of calling AnyMessageType.decode... am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java pack-unpack is used when `Any` transports *another protobuf message encoded in it*. When your `Any` transports just a string, then you obviously don't need to call any decode. Your decode/unpack is `value.toString('utf-8')`. You are accessing directly `Any`'s members `type_url` and `value`, which is what Java's pack-unpack is abstracting you from.

When you would want to transport a protobuf `ThatMessageType` in `details` instead of simple string, then you would need `ThatMessageType.encode()` instead of just creating a Buffer, and `ThatMessageType.decode()` instead of calling `toString`.

Comment: Pavel, thanks for confirming my assumptions. This was exactly my understanding (in my example, value.toString is an 'association' to unpack). Your latter suggestion : that is great! I did a quick test and it works like a charm. For some reason (I guess the definition of Any : "the Any message type lets you use messages as embedded types without having their .proto definition") I did not think about it, but in the end it is about providing a Buffer in AnyMessage for value and "later" being able to decode it - thanks for this!